# I have two data dict type data sets whose keys are same tuples. how can I concatenate them and print in tabulate form?

Tags: python

Below is the part of my programs.

```
mle_prob = {k: v / tokens.count(k[0])
        for k, v in bi_freq.iteritems()}
bigram_count = sum(bi_freq.itervalues())
bi_prob = {k: v / bigram_count
       for k, v in bi_freq.iteritems()}
for k, v in sorted(mle_prob.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True):
    print(k, v)
for k, v in sorted(bi_prob.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True):
    print(k, v)
```

the final printing result I want is like this.

```
Bigram    Mle_prob    bi_prob
(      )     v1          x1
(      )     v2          x2
```

I've never heard about data type that can handle one key and its two values...should I concatenating two dict? or modify the data type?

Comment: Can't you use a dictionary that its value are a 2-emenets list?

Comment: Are you trying to make a dict that associates a key with 2 values? In that case you should just associate to a tuple, e.g. dict = {a: (1,2)}

Comment: can you give your two inputs in the question? as such your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Looking at your last few questions which in fact are around same problem it seems you first need to have a good understanding about `python` itself. Please at least go through the tutorial etc. and do some practice before asking these type of general questions.